# Summing and averaging rows with values in common (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, average

I would like to SUM rows that have a common value in a column then take the average based on another common value in another column.

Ex:
[image]

I would like to SUM the the number of workers in each week and each shift. (So shift 1111 should have 15 workers for week 1 and 14 for week 2.) Then I would like average number of workers of all the weeks for each shift. (For shift 1111, the average of 14 and 15 is 14.5)

The result should be:
[image]

Could someone help me with the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select
    shift, avg(num_workers) avg_workers
from
    (
        select
            shift, week_number, sum(current_workers) num_workers
        from
            work_sheet t
        group by
            shift, week_number
    )
group by
    shift
```

Which I think is also equivalent to something like:

```sql
select
    shift, sum(current_workers)/count(distinct week_number) avg_workers
from
    work_sheet t
group by
    shift
```